# Proof check: being reduced is a local property (Atiyah-Macdonald 3.5)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, localization

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit. Show that $A$ is reduced iff for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$, $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is reduced.

This corresponds more or less to exercise 5, chapter 3 of Atiyah-Macdonald. It is useful to remember that  $\text{Nil}(A_{\mathfrak{p}})=(\text{Nil}(A))_{\mathfrak{p}}$  (*).

($\Rightarrow$) Obvious by (*).

($\Leftarrow$) By the fact that "being $0$" is a local property which is satisfied by $\text{Nil}(A)$, again because of (*).

I wonder if the argument for the $\Leftarrow$ is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, it is. More formally you can say $\;\operatorname{Supp}(\operatorname{Nil}(A))=\varnothing$.

Comment: Sorry! What do you mean? Is that if $A$ has no nilpotent element then $A_{P}$ has no nilpotent element?

Comment: @LêThếLong $A$ reduced means that $A$ has no nonzero nilpotents.

Comment: So, the problem means that $A$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements iff $A_{P}$ is too with $P\in Spec{A}$? If it is that then the "$\Rightarrow"$ is not true.

Comment: @LêThếLong why not? If $Nil(A)=0$ then of course $(Nil(A))_P=Nil(A_P)=0$

Comment: You can not conclude like that. If you take $ \frac{a}{1} \in A_{P}$ such that it is nilpotent. It means there exists  $s\in R\P$  and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $sa^{n}=0$. How can you deduce that A has non-zero nilpotent elements?

Comment: @LêThếLong if $sa^n=0$ then $(sa)^n=0$, and $sa\neq 0$ otherwise $\frac{a}{1}=0$ in $A_P$

Comment: I see. That is my mistake. I remember about this one: $x$ is nilpotent iff $\frac{x}{1}$ is nilpotent. It is wrong but not relevance to this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This question was posted a while ago, but I'll add a more explicit answer just for my own reference in the future.

Let $A$ be a nonzero commutative unital ring, so that $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is reduced for every prime $\mathfrak{p}$. Suppose (towards a contradiction) that $x \in A$ is nilpotent and nonzero. Then its annihilator $\text{Ann}(x) \subsetneq A$ is a non-zero ideal of $A$ (and is proper since it does not contain 1). By Zorn's lemma, it is contained in a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Then the image of $x$ in the localization $A \to A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is zero. This means that $\frac{x}{1} \sim \frac{0}{1}$, so there exists a $u \in A-\mathfrak{m}$ so that $0 = (1\cdot 0 - x\cdot 1)u = xu$, hence $u \in \text{Ann}(x)$. But this is a contradiction since this says $u \in \mathfrak{m}$, hence we conclude that $x=0$, and so $A$ is reduced. In fact we have an even stronger statement:

**Theorem**: The following are equivalent:

1. $A$ is reduced
2. $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is reduced for every prime $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$
3. $A_\mathfrak{m}$ is reduced for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subset A$

The proofs $(1)\implies (2)\implies (3)$ are trivial, and the content of the discussion above shows $(3)\implies (1)$.

Comment: $\def\nil{\operatorname{Nil}}$Another way of proving your theorem is by applying 3.8 of Atiyah, MacDonald, combined with the observation that $S^{-1}\nil A=\nil S^{-1}A$, where $\nil A=\sqrt{0}$ is the nilradical, and $S\subset A$ is a multiplicatively closed subset. More generally, $S^{-1}\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{S^{-1}I}$, for $I\subset A$ an ideal.